# Using clojure.browser.event.unlisten in ClojureScript One project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying my hand a writing a clojureScript One project, but I'm having trouble removing an event listener (unlisten) - listener is registered with this code:

```
(defn- add-expand_fold-listener
"Accepts a ele-id and creates listeners for click events on div
which will then fire rendering changes"
[ele-id]
(log/log "adding opening listeners")
(event/listen (single-node (by-id ele-id))
    "click"
#(dispatch/fire (re-class ele-id "foldup" "expand"))))
```

But when I try to unlisten with this code:

```
(defn- remove-expand_fold-listener
 "Accepts a ele-id and removes listener for click events on div"
 [ele-id]
 (log/log "removing opening listener")
(event/unlisten (by-id ele-id) 
      "click" 
      #(dispatch/fire (re-class ele-id "foldup" "expand")) 
      false)
(log/log "done removing listener"))
```

The code runs with no errors but the listener is not removed, I guess I have a syntax error, but I'm not sure where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks Larry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Instead of trying to use domina (which is good stuff but not all of the functions are in the lein-deps) and trying to use the clojureScript One event model finally just went right to the source... added to the require section of the namespace:

```
[goog.events :as g-events]
```

Then in the remove function used:

```
(g-events/removeAll (by-id ele-id) "click")
```

And it works like a champ.
Hope this helps someone in the future...

Answer (score 0):

In DOM you can attach many event handlers to a single element, so when you want to remove an event handler the DOM need to know which particular event handler you want to remove. In your code the attaching of event handler creates a new handler function and attach it and in the other code it creates another new function (although the code is same) and tries to unlisten it, so basically it doesn't work as you need to pass the same function object to unlisten that you used while binding the event.

To solve this you need to define the handler as a function with a name (not anonymous) and use that function in bind and unbind events.

```
(defn myHandler [& args] (dispatch/fire (re-class ele-id "foldup" "expand")))
```

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work. It seems I can't use a function like that to bind to the event, I tried many ways but it only adds the listener when used in an anonymous way, so never got to the unlisten part. Thanks Ankur